# Variable hoverSphereTransform of SteamVR is not assigned

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steam, steamvr

I keep getting this "error" (The variable hoverSphereTransform of Hand has not been assigned.) after adding the camera[rig] to my scene. Is an error that appears constantly but when I run the project it works fine, just appears constantly in the console. Why is it appearing and how to fix it?

I understand that it asks to assign a variable, and i know where in the inspector to assign it, but I cant find what to assign.

I have tried searching online but I cant find anything. This is the third PC I try this and all show me the same, so I dont think is my particular setup. What am i missing?

Thank you!

Comment: How are we suppose to tell you the cause and how to fix the error without knowing what it is? (Add the error message to your question.)

Comment: OK, the error literally is what the question is, but I see your point. Edited.

Comment: Did you add the SteamVR Tracked Controllers to your camerarig(On the left and right controllers under it in the hierchy) after removing your main camera?  Is this also in the latest version of SteamVR?  Please include your unity version as well.  (going to try and recreate it...)

Comment: I downloaded the SteamVR version yesterday, so if not the latest, one of them. When you say, "Did you add the SteamVR Tracked Controllers to your camerarig" I basically added the [CameraRig] and it has the Controller (left) and Controller (right) prefabs. Inside it has another that is called "Model" with a script called "Steam VR_Render Model. For what you are saying, am I missing to add a model here? Because in the scene when I run it the basic controllers appear.

Comment: I looked at a tutorial for how to setup SteamVR, their first steps before they ran it was adding the [CameraRig] prefab, and then adding scripts to the 2 controllers under that camera rig, the scripts were `SteamVR Tracked Controllers` these scripts are added to the `Controller (left)` and `Controller (right)` prefabs.  I asked the SteamVR version because it is also available on github, not sure if you got yours form GIThub or the Unity Asset Store.

Comment: Which tutorial you saw? I believe this might be an old one as "SteamVR Tracked Controllers" script is from before SteamVR 2.0. Now the CameraRig comes with the controllers and the scripts "Steam VR_Behaviour_Pose" already added and then I added the "Hand" script as in another tutotial was mentioned. Then is when I got the problem. It works, but complains.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to "uncheck" fallbackhand i.e turn it off just below the inspector tab. i also did it for fallback objects just in case as well seemed to have worked i didn't get the error again.  I also have to say the none of the tutorials or written documents that i could find to get the steamVR working with teleport were correct/complete... I've been pulling me hair out for 2 days. but have finally pieced it all together.